# How to extract hyperlinked hrefs from html using urllib2

Tags: python, pagination, web-scraping, urllib2

I am using urllib2 to pull the html contents of a web page. My plan is to iterate through the page numbers provided at the bottom of the page (a take on pagination). However, the link for each of the page listings on the bottom of the page are provided by hyperlinks in the href tag. For example, the links to the corresponding web page for each page number is a link associated with the '#' symbol (i.e. right clicking on the '#' and opening the link in a new tab leads to the page):

```
        <li class="currentPage">3</li>



        <li><a class = "_pageNo" href='#'>4</a></li>



        <li><a class = "_pageNo" href='#'>5</a></li>



        <li><a class = "_pageNo" href='#'>6</a></li>
```

When i pull the contents, the '#' are retrieved as characters rather than their underlying links. Any thoughts?

Comment: are you looking to get the `["4", "5", "6"]` from the links or you want to follow them? there might be a javascript being executed.

Comment: I'm looking to pull the hyperlinks associated with each of the '#'. For example, when viewing source, if I right click the '#' in the following line:<li><a class = "_pageNo" href='#'>4</a></li> and open the link in a new tab, its the fourth page as indicated. What I am trying to do is access this underlying hyperlinks from all '#' in the href class.

Comment: So, what you need is to get the "4" or "5" or "6" and make the link with information you will find on the page.

Comment: If the URL were a function of the page numbers (4,5,6, etc.) then that would suffice. However, the url is static across these pages- thus, the need for a way to tap those hyperlinked hrefs.

Comment: can you share the page you're referring to?

Comment: Sure: view-source:http://online.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=alibaba

Comment: A quick search for "_pageNo" will navigate you to the content in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting the page you mentioned in the comments, I found out that when you click a link, a `POST` is sent back to the server informing which page to see next, so, to fetch a specific page, you will need to do this:

```
from urllib import urlencode
import urllib2

url ='http://online.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=alibaba'
data = urlencode({'page_no':3})

contents = urllib2.urlopen(url, data=data).read()
```

I would also suggest using the lib `requests` for this, which would simplify the code.